# Django get objects that are foreign key of two models

Tags: sql, django

I have the following three models where Budget and Sale both contain a foreign key to Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    # ...

class Budget(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ...

class Sale(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ...
```

I want to get a queryset of all Customer objects for which both a Budget and Sale exists. I initially tried getting the intersection of the customer field of all Budget and Sale objects:

```
customers = {
    budget.customer for budget in Budget.objects.all()
} & {
    sale.customer for sale in Sale.objects.all()
}
```

This returns the correct objects, but becomes horribly inefficient as the size of my database grows.

How can I retrieve these objects in a more efficient way? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Customer.objects.filter(
    budget__isnull=False,
    sale__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

Django can follow `ForeignKey`s in reverse. It uses the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for the name of relation. If that is not specified, it falls back on the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) parameter, and if that is not specified, it will use the name of the model in lowercase, so `budget` and `sale`. We here make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s on the `Budget` and `Sale` table, and check if for both there is a non-null row. Likely the Django ORM will optimize this to `INNER JOIN`s.